Yacc/Bison generic function expression shift/reduce conflict
I am trying to implement a grammar for complex expressions that include comparisons, identifiers, and even generic function invocations.
All of these should be legal expressions:
Simple identifier:
myVar

Simple comparison:
myVar < yourVar

Generic function invocation:
myFunction < int > ()

Comparison chaining is not allowed: a < b > c or any other variation
I now get a shift/reduce conflict, with the following minimal reproducible example grammar:
%token ID OP_GT OP_LT OPEN_PARANT CLOSE_PARANT

%nonassoc COMPARISON
%nonassoc GENERIC

%start expr

%%

expr:
    basic_expr
    | comp_expr
    ;

basic_expr:
    ID
    | function_call_expr
    ;

function_call_expr:
    ID OPEN_PARANT CLOSE_PARANT
    | ID OP_LT ID OP_GT OPEN_PARANT CLOSE_PARANT %prec GENERIC
    ;

comp_expr:
    basic_expr OP_LT basic_expr     %prec COMPARISON
    | basic_expr OP_GT basic_expr   %prec COMPARISON
    ;
%%

I tried looking for some posts and references on precedences and other techniques to solve this but to no avail. (note the %nonassocs and %precs)
Here is the report on the conflicting state, as generated by the verbose bison option:
state 1

    3 basic_expr: ID .
    5 function_call_expr: ID . OPEN_PARANT CLOSE_PARANT
    6                   | ID . OP_LT ID OP_GT OPEN_PARANT CLOSE_PARANT

    OP_LT        shift, and go to state 6
    OPEN_PARANT  shift, and go to state 7

    OP_LT     [reduce using rule 3 (basic_expr)]
    $default  reduce using rule 3 (basic_expr)


This requires semantic feedback to the lexer.

Or else you need at least 3 symbols of lookahead.
